# step by step filtering drupal view

Tags: views

hi i have a site in which i want to show items, now i want to be able to filter the items based on several paramaters (*note the parameters aren't related to one another which is why dependency filter module isnt the solution.)

what i want to do is the user can choose a value and filter the results by it, then the remaining filters and filter values would only be ones that have items remaining that fit the criteria.

an example if the items are computer screens and i have 3 attributes - color, width, company
then if a user chooses hp for company and they only have white screens then i will only see white as an option in the color filter.
if i choose dell and they have black and white then both colors will show on the filter.

is there a module that achives this affect, if not is there a way for me to do it myself (im pretty new to drupal i understand what hooks are but not to familiar with them and never developed a module).

Comment: Have you looked at [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi)

Comment: didnt know this was the name of the wanted functionality +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) with [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) to create search pages with dynamic filters like [here](http://drupaljobs.epiqo.com/search/job) but you can use another modules like [Ajax facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_facets) if you need checkboxes or select lists as filter widgets.

Search API needs also a database backend ([Search API Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db)).

Comment: thx, seems to be that those are all the modules i needed, a grood video that ties it all together : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcAM0HrEk4c

Comment: one question though - seems i need each filter to be indexed how much of a performance impact does this method have?

Comment: It depends - of course - how many entities (like "core" entities: nodes, taxonomy terms & vocabularies, users or other, made available by contributed modules, e.g.: [profiles](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2), [files](https://www.drupal.org/project/media), [relations](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) do you have and which one are indexed - you can create different indexes for particular entity types. A good news is you can disable the Search module provided by Drupal core (and truncate its index table) if you would decide to use Search API.